# How to add inline script tags to Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm trying to integrate Piwik and Intercom into my Nuxt 3 application. Previously, I was able to use the special `app.html` file in the project root, but that feature is not available anymore. I can use the `useHead()` utility or the Nuxt configuration, but I don't have a URL for the `src` attribute, just an inline script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is a solution that is a bit hidden, because it is not part of the Nuxt documentation as it is the responsibility of the [unhead](https://unhead.unjs.io/) package. The property is called `textContent`. So using the `useHead()` utility or the [`app.head.script` array in `nuxt.config.ts`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#head), it is possible to create an inline script tag:

```js
useHead({
  script: [
    {
      textContent: `/* Inline code goes here ... */`
      tagPosition: "bodyClose",
    },
  ],
});
```

Using the `tagPosition` property, the script tag can be placed in the head, beginning of body or end of body. Valid values are: `'head' | 'bodyClose' | 'bodyOpen'`.

There is also the `innerHTML` property. The comments for this say:

> Text content of the tag. Warning: This is not safe for XSS. Do not use this with user input, use `textContent` instead.

More information on this in the [unhead documentation](https://unhead.unjs.io/usage/guides/inner-content).